# how to use the break clause in this specific case

Tags: python, python-2.7, break

I'm trying to use the break statement in a loop. I am trying to build a function that finds the largest prime number less than a given number by user, `userInput`. Here is my code:

```
def primeFinder():
    aVar = 2 # This is a possible factor
    divisorList = []  # This is a factor list of userInout, the inputted number
    while aVar <= userInput: # Checking until the variable cannot be a factor
            if userInput % aVar == 0: # If userInput divided by the variable has a remainder of zero, it means it is a factor
                    divisorList.append(aVar) # Adding the factor to th factor list
                    aVar+=1 # Making the possible factor numeral one bigger to test again
            else:
                    aVar +=1 # Making the possible factor numeral one bigger to test again

    print divisorList
    if len(divisorList) > 1:  # If there are more than one factor...
            print "Your input",userInput, " is not prime" # It is not prime
    else:   
            print "Your input", userInput," is prime."  # It is prime
```

I need to know where to put the break statement to stop the program when I have found the largest prime. Where do I put it and why?
The return function doesn't work. Here's what happens:

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 25, 40, 50, 100, 125, 200, 250, 500, 1000]
Your input 1000  is not prime
[3, 9, 27, 37, 111, 333, 999]
Your input 999  is not prime
[2, 499, 998]
Your input 998  is not prime
[997]
Your input 997  is prime.
[2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 83, 166, 249, 332, 498, 996]
Your input 996  is not prime
[5, 199, 995]
Your input 995  is not prime
[2, 7, 14, 71, 142, 497, 994]
Your input 994  is not prime
[3, 331, 993]
Your input 993  is not prime
[2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 32, 62, 124, 248, 496, 992]
Your input 992  is not prime
[991]
Your input 991  is prime.
[2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 18, 22, 30, 33, 45, 55, 66, 90, 99, 110,     165,     198, 330, 495, 990]
Your input 990  is not prime
```

Comment: Do you mean the largest prime number less than 1000 ;)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use xrange for better performance when n is too large:

```
from math import sqrt


def is_prime(n):
    if n in (2, 3):
        return True

    for i in xrange(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    return True


def find_largest_prime(n):
    for i in xrange(n - 1, 1, -1):
        if is_prime(i):
            return i

print(find_largest_prime(1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you better iterate from top to bottom to get the largest prime factor. Like this:

```
primeFactor=1
for aVar in range(userInput-1,1,-1): #loop from userInput-1 to 2
    if userInput % aVar == 0:
        primeFactor=aVar
        break;

print "The largest prime factor is "+str(primeFactor).
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have so far looks pretty good. What the function you have described does is find if a given (single) integer is a prime. What you have to do now is just start from 1000 and go down until you find a prime.

I think it's cleaner to just return `True` or `False` based on whether the number is prime. It's also a little cleaner to accept `userInput` as an argument to your prime finding function. So, you could change your function to be like so:

```
def primeFinder(userInput):
    aVar = 2 # This is a possible factor
    divisorList = []  # This is a factor list of userInout, the inputted number
    while aVar <= userInput: # Checking until the variable cannot be a factor
            if userInput % aVar == 0: # If userInput divided by the variable has a remainder of zero, it means it is a factor
                    divisorList.append(aVar) # Adding the factor to th factor list
                    aVar+=1 # Making the possible factor numeral one bigger to test again
            else:
                    aVar +=1 # Making the possible factor numeral one bigger to test again

    #print divisorList
    if len(divisorList) > 1:  # If there are more than one factor...
            return False
    else:
            return True
```

and then, to find the max (using break, as per your question) you could do this:

```
for num in range(1000, -1, -1): # count down from 1000
    if primeFinder(num):
        print "The largest prime under 1000 is:"
        print num
        break # Break out of loop after we've found largest result, as per question
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mwm314.This is going to be very helpful.